# convexHull in 3D Perl

Tags: perl, 3d, convex-hull, qhull

I have a Set of points in 3D with x y z coordinates. i would lik eto calculate the convex Hull of these points. I haf gone through algorithms available but i couldnt do it in Perl. Perl Math:ConvextHull module also i have checked but i didnt get how to give these 3D points as input.   Please help me.

```
                 X        Y       Z

POINT   1     -15.037   7.344  14.621  
POINT   2     -15.467   6.281  15.522  
POINT   3     -15.147   6.738  16.954  
POINT   4     -13.998   7.141  17.197  
POINT   5     -14.697   4.973  15.165  
POINT   6     -15.115   4.480  13.780  
POINT   7     -14.965   3.895  16.188  
POINT   8     -16.607   4.347  13.471  
POINT   9     -16.087   6.731  17.929  
POINT  10     -15.826   6.999  19.343  
POINT  11     -15.144   5.847  20.038
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Math::ConvexHull`](https://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aConvexHull) won't help because it only works with 2D data (X and Y).

Unfortunately it looks like [`Math::Geometry::Planar`](https://metacpan.org/module/Math%3a%3aGeometry%3a%3aPlanar) has the same limitation.

Comment: ... and Math::ConvexHull::MonotoneChain (the successor to Math::ConvexHull) won't help really help for 3D either. For 3D, my limited understanding is that you'd probably want to implement Chan's algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Half an answer: perhaps you can solve your problem by driving the [Qhull](http://qhull.org) library/accompanying command-line programs from Perl.

I didn't test because I don't know the math.